# How would you convince a hozer beshe'ela of the truth of Judaism?

Tags: tanach, apostasy

As adherents of the Jewish faith, what would you do to convince someone לחזור בתשובה? not merely a Jew espousing secular lifestyle, but one that is agnostic and that does not believe the Tanakh is the inspired word of God. What is the indisputable proof of the Jewish faith?

Comment: What's a hozer beshe'ela? never heard of that term

Comment: @robev roughly Israeli equivalent to American "off the derech". Grew up religious Jew who is no longer religious. It's a pun on "teshuva"

Comment: @DoubleAA, what's the difference between חוזר בשאלה and דתל"ש ?